# Can i somehow use plink on web for SSH check?

Tags: linux, web, ssh, plink

How i have SSH checker on PHP. It works with SSH2 and libssh2, but this modules work bad with some SSH. Plink works great with all SSH servers on Windows, but is there a way to run plink on linux? Or maybe i can use something else for WEB?

Answer (score 0):

You can get plink for linux here:

http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/download.shtml

Generally you can do everything in ssh(1) that you can do with plink. If you can show us what you're trying to do, maybe we can give you a solution that uses ssh(1).